# How to tell if a list does not contain an element?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a small program in which checks to see if the box is checked and if it is it will add an element to the list "names". But I need it to check if the name isn't already in the list before it adds the element.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: [5th entry from google for "c# list does not contain"](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-contains), wouldn't be very difficult for anyone to figure out the next step

Comment: @Sayse as of today, this question is now the top search on Google for that phrase ;)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method

```
if (!myList.Contains("name"))
{
    myList.Add("name");
}
```

Or [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method

```
if (!myList.Any(s => s == "name"))
{
    myList.Add("name");
}
```

would do the job. You don't specify whether the check is case sensitive or not, these checks are both **case sensitive** but it's easy enough to update for case insensitive checks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead, it's designed to not allow any duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `All` query LINQ:

```cs
if (myList.All(s => s != "name"))
{
    myList.Add("name");
}
```